# ZXing barcode scanner for .NET

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use this library https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/ .
Images are successfully decoded on this site https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx, but not in my code.

Here are two ways that I have tried:

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true, TryInverted = true, PossibleFormats = fmts };
Result result = reader.Decode(new Bitmap(@"D:\\6.jpg"));
```

and:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

---

```
MultiFormatReader m_BarcodeReader = new MultiFormatReader();
var hints = new Dictionary<DecodeHintType, object>();
var fmts = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
fmts.Add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);
hints.Add(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER_WITHOUT_ROTATION, false);
hints.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, fmts);

Result rawResult;
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"D:\\6.jpg");
RGBLuminanceSource r = new RGBLuminanceSource(ImageToByte(image), image.Width, image.Height);
GlobalHistogramBinarizer x = new
HybridBinarizer(r);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(x);
try
{
    rawResult = m_BarcodeReader.decode(bitmap, hints);

    if (rawResult != null)
    {
        return rawResult.Text;
    }
}
catch (ReaderException e)
{

}
```

In both cases the result of decoding is `null`. What am I doing wrong here?
Here is the sample image:

[image]

Comment: Did you try with simple barcode images?

Comment: Can you display the image in a windows form?  Maybe adjust height, width, left top so only bar code is passed to scanner.  Rotate image if necessary.

Comment: @VishnuPrasad, it works here and there in very specific circumstances that I can not detect. Mostly it just doesn't work, while every picture is decoded on the site https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Comment: @jdweng, it should take the barcode automatically without intervention.

Comment: In case someone will search for this, I gave up to make this working and went with another one https://freebarcode.codeplex.com/ . Last is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally made a total restart as is was not working as expected.

I implemented the following algorythm: If the decoder doesn't read the barcode, split the image in 4 and restart.

It worked pretty well after and I think this is how the website you mentionned is working. Too bad it doesn't use this method from scratch.

<sup>note: this code is far from perfect, makes a lot of assumptions, if you copy it and use it *as is*, it may crash if your image is not in the same format that the one provided by the OP</sup>

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly List<BarcodeFormat>  Fmts = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.All_1D };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap originalBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\6.jpg");
        Bitmap img = CropImage(originalBitmap, new Rectangle(0 , 0, originalBitmap.Width, originalBitmap.Height));
        int width = img.Width;
        int heigth = img.Height;
        int nbOfFrames = 1;
        bool found = false;
        while (!found && width > 10 && heigth > 10)
        {
            if (DecodeImg(img))
            {
                break;
            }
            nbOfFrames *= 4;
            width /= 2;
            heigth /= 2;
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < nbOfFrames; i++)
            {
                img.Dispose();
                img = new Bitmap(CropImage(originalBitmap, new Rectangle(x, y, width, heigth)));

                if (DecodeImg(img))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                x += width;
                if (x < originalBitmap.Width)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                x = 0;
                y += heigth;
                if (y >= originalBitmap.Height)
                {
                    y = 0;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public static Bitmap CropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
    {
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
        return bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    }

    public static bool DecodeImg(Bitmap img)
    {
        BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            TryInverted = true,
            Options =
            {
                PossibleFormats = Fmts,
                TryHarder = true,
                ReturnCodabarStartEnd = true,
                PureBarcode = false
            }
        };
        Result result = reader.Decode(img);

        if (result != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.BarcodeFormat);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
            return true;
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Raté");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, it results in null on my machine. Can you please upload the solution somewhere?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I will, just give me an hour

Comment: may be I am using some incorrect library version? I have this nuget package installed `<package id="ZXing.Net" version="0.14.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />`. Can you check yours?

Comment: In case someone will search for this, I gave up to make this working and went with another one https://freebarcode.codeplex.com/ . Last is working perfectly.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I was not using the correct file in the previous answer, sorry. Now it works pretty well

Comment: thank you very much. Now it works, but can not decode some files, while another sdk(that I provided earlier) is working fine.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub sir plz upload solution somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: @JaydeepKarena the code I provided *is* one solution. I'm not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: @JaydeepKarena then you can ask a new question and explain what's wrong with your implementation. I'll be glad to take a look at it.